# torsocks[30239]: [connect] Connection to a local address are denied

Tags: torsocks

I want to open a shared folder at home for me to access at work, because most ftp is blocked by firewall I though I'd find an inventive way to access my files.
On my remote host (at home) I host a tor hidden service that will forward all traffic to port 445 (SMB).

On my workstation I want to connect to this SMB-files by using this command:

`torsocks smbclient -L \\address.onion -p<port#> -N`

But this seems to return following warning:

> WARNING torsocks[30239]: [connect] Connection to a local address are denied since it might be a TCP DNS query to a local DNS server. Rejecting it for safety reasons. (in tsocks_connect() at connect.c:186)
>
> Connection to address.onion failed (Error NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED)

But I can't seem to figure out what causes this error, nor do I know how to fix this.

Please help thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will **not** be able to use SMB *directly* through Tor - it needs UDP, and Tor provides TCP only. Use an OpenVPN with TCP port on your hidden service, connect to your hidden service's VPN server - and go through right into your home lan without any problems

Comment: As I recall, SMB is a TCP- protocol, how would this need UDP ?

Comment: It's in vital need of TCP**+UDP** ports 137-139, or it will fail an authentication like in the message you cited in your question